# Kubuntu freezes during launch

Tags: boot, kubuntu, 15.04

Good evening everyone.

I have a weird bug since yesterday.
I have installed  kubuntu 15.04 since his release with no problems. Nevertheless, 
since yesterday, every time I start my laptop, ~10 seconds after bios messages, screen stay black and kubuntu never launch. I have to restart my computer, start recovery mode and resume to be able to launch Kubuntu.

I have restarted my computer several times, I have my computer updated. I don't know what to do.

If you have any idea of what's going on, I would be grateful.

EDIT':

[A link with a .txt of command result](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=59130726405535323523)

Comment: Could you [edit] your question, adding the contents of the `dmesg` command, so we can know what is actually going on?

Answer (score 0):

its happen because you did not install Kubuntu with propre way. reinstall kubuntu again with bugfree proper disk.